# Why was this question deleted by "community"?

Tags: support

See the question [Is this circuit OK for a Nixie Tube clock?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/344999/4512).

I know it wasn't a great question and it was at -2, but it did have one answer at +2, and that answer was accepted.  One of the two points in the single answer ended up not applying due to the OP providing incomplete information.  The other point is still valid and possibly useful to the OP.

I could understand if the OP got frustrated and deleted the question.  But, it got deleted by "community", which is a bot as I understand it.  I thought only questions with no answers with positive score got cleaned up automatically.

Obviously I'm misunderstanding something.  How does the "community" cleanup algorithm really work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question got deleted because the user account itself was deleted.

The account was deleted by the user himself.

Comment: Ah, that's a wrinkle I hadn't thought of.  It makes more sense now.

Comment: However, note that [he's back](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/345199/11683) with a brand-new account!

Comment: Looks like he's trying to get around the automatic ban due to bad posts, or people remembering how he jerked us around with the nixie tube question already.  I guess that's why you mods make the bug bucks!  I see his new question is already at -2, so it looks like he's not getting away with it.